# Anomaly detection program with Spark using clustering

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I'm working on several projects using Apache Spark and I've been stuck on the anomaly/outlier detection part.

I used a clustering technique to find anomalies with the idea that anomalies/outliers will make their own cluster, meaning that the data point considered anomalous is in fact a cluster center. This works if there are only few outliers relevant to the amount of data, but if there are a lot, it fails to work. Here is my code so far: https://github.com/Guillermo19/MyTest/blob/3511d33f5c7336adef04f2f93a69f1af7865e066/anomalyDetection.java

I'm confident that my idea that outliers become cluster centers is correct, but it depends on the amount of clusters generated, and so far there is no relationship between the data itself and the amount of clusters, and so I can't find a way to increase the clusters based on the amount of possible outliers.

What can I fix/modify in my program to correctly display the outliers using clustering?

OR if I can solve this using a different method tell me. I personally think that clustering is one of the most viable and best way to find outliers...

EDIT: Here is the data I've been working so far, with the expected outlier results:

First file:

```
Name    Size    Records
File1   1000    104370
File2   997     103121
File3   1500    109123
File4   2170    113888
File5   2000    111974
File6   1820    110666
File7   1200    106771
File8   1500    108991
File9   1000    104007
File10  1300    107037
File11  1900    111109
File12  1430    108051
File13  1780    110006
File14  2010    114449
File15  2017    114889
File16  800     88812 //possible outlier. My program does indeed show this
File17  1307    107098
File18  1519    109321
File19  1641    110777
File20  1056    104888
```

Second file:

```
Name    Size    Records
File1   1013    105727
File2   980     104230
File3   1520    110542
File4   2198    115369
File5   2026    113430
File6   1844    112105
File7   1216    108159
File8   1520    110408
File9   1013    105359
File10  1317    108428
File11  1925    112553
File12  1449    109456
File13  1803    111436
File14  2036    115937
File15  2043    116383
File16  1002    105177
File17  1324    108490
File18  1539    110742
File19  1662    112630
File20  1070    106589
```

`//no outliers, and my program does show that`

Third file:

```
Name    Size    Records
File1   1100    50 //anomalous
File2   1003    106712
File3   1556    113174
File4   2250    500000 //anomalous
File5   2074    116131
File6   1888    114774
File7   1245    110734
File8   1556    113037
File9   1037    229999 //anomalous
File10  1348    111569
File11  1971    115233
File12  1484    112062
File13  1846    114089
File14  2084    118698
File15  2092    118564
File16  1026    107681
File17  1356    111073
File18  1576    113379
File19  1702    114889
File20  1325    70000 //anomalous
```

My program in this third file only recognizes the File4 and File9 as anomalous, and doesn't show File1 and File20. I'm positive they are both grouped together, which is why they won't show up. I want to avoid anomalous data being grouped together, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It's hard to say without a proper exploration of data. Taking the problem into Spark directly isn't the correct approach. Rather start small by prototyping and exploring your data and maybe visualizing it to find outlier. I don't think you will be able to get a concrete answer in the questions current state.

Comment: I already did and like I said my program shows the correct answer when there are few outliers (like 1 or 2 for a total of 20 records). I wanted to know why this approach doesn't work as the number of outliers increases and if there is a way to go around this. I read multiple articles about this and they all said that anomalies/outliers do, indeed, make their own cluster. You are right, though, in that maybe tagging spark into this problem might not help that much...

Comment: you may know the data you have because you have access to it. But we can't tell what is it about by just looking at your code. You should add a minimum reproducible and verifiable example and not just the code. This means code + data

Comment: Problem is I'm working with dummy data. This is suppose to be part of a big project, but I don't have the real data to work with as of now. I can post the dummy data that I've been working with. Let me do that.

Comment: That would be a good idea (posting that dummy data). Working with real data might lead to different results but a machine learning project always start with prototyping.

Comment: Thanks for the patience and advice. I will do that now. :)

Comment: I added the dummy data. Hopefully this will help people understand what I'm trying to do

Comment: And why are those points anomalies you think ? Any domain knowledge behind that ?

Comment: No specific knowledge. They are considered anomalous because they don't follow the rules of the other data. The higher the size the higher the records, and the lower the size the lower the records. However, the records should increase or decrease at a considerable rate, and not by a lot. They should still be within the domain of the other records in the dataset.

Comment: If I increase the amount of clusters, my program does end up showing all the anomalies, but I don't know how to automatically increase the clusters based on the possible anomalies... :/ I am positive there is no way to implement this idea, so that's why I was asking for alternative ways to use clustering

Comment: I don't get your last comment. But from a first overview of your data, you definitely have more than 2 clusters.

Comment: Yes, hierarchical clustering (BisectingKMeans in my program) does find an adequate number of clusters based on the amount of records (rows). In my case I have 4 clusters. I already checked. I meant on my last comment that I don't think there is a way to correlate the amount of possible outliers with the amount of clusters, meaning that it might not be possible to make my program increase the amount of clusters based on the possible outliers (or any other data that is affected by them, like standard deviation, etc)

Comment: unfortunately you'll have to code that yourself. Picking the number of cluster that minimizes the within-cluster sum of square (wss) per example with an elbow method

Comment: Yes, I know I have to code it myself. I just don't know how to code it because I don't know how to correlate the number of clusters with the outliers. The elbow method indeed finds the correct amount of clusters, but then again it is based on the amount of records, not the data itself, meaning that adding outliers won't increment the number of clusters, and that won't solve my problem. I'm still open for other alternatives to find outliers using clustering, but nobody else has commented yet :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148072/discussion-between-eliasah-and-guillermo-herrera).

Answer (score 5):

People have tried k-means for anomaly detection, but it did not work very well.

Just imagine you have two very similar outliers. They will be one cluster. Even when not similar you will quite often see more than one outlier in such a cluster.

If you have clusters of different density, this method often won't detect outliers close to the dense cluster. Nor outliers inbetween of clusters.

Because of the random seed and the problem of choosing k the method is fragile and hard to use. Also, you need to choose a large k usually, and the runtime then grows a lot.

Instead, people mostly use nearest neighbor outlier detection and LOF, the local outlier factor. Since you are on the JVM, try loading your data into ELKI and experiment with some of its outlier detection methods. The k-means clustering of ELKI is also much faster than Spark, and if I remember correctly, **it already contains a method to detect outliers with k-means** for comparison.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I do realize now that k-means might not be the best way to find outliers... I can't work on ELKI since my company and project as a whole works with Spark, and it would cause problems if I introduce a new framework at this point. However, are the neighbor outlier detection and LOF clustering based or something new? I will certainly look into them now

Comment: No, they don't use clustering. You don't want to rely on clustering, because clustering is difficult and brittle. With outliers, you need something very robust. But some clustering like DBSCAN and OPTICS can identify "noise" points, which don't belong to any cluster!

Comment: I got it! To be honest, I also don't think clustering might be a good approach. I went with it because my manager told me I should use it, but I'm going to tell him there are other feasible solutions. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I was awaiting for your answer @Anony-Mousse :)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I have a question: what do you think of making a clustering model where I tell it that I only want two clusters, with half of the data points in each. I then try to find those points who are far away from the cluster center and consider those anomalous. Would you say that's a good approach? I colleague told me that and thought of asking you before looking more into it

Comment: I think that is what the k-means outlier thing in ELKI may be doing, and it doesn't appear to work well. Assume you have a single Gaussian. K-means will cut it into two, and there will be points at the very center of the Gaussian that arequitefar from the k-means center. Look at kNN outlier and LOF instead. No need to bet on being lucky with clustering.

Comment: But you really should just try and benchmark all those approaches. Maybe they work on your data, maybe they don't.